# Sending message using facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I wish to develop an Android app where the user can send messages by clicking a button and the send dialog box should appear whereby the user can send personal message to his friends.

However, this is not well documented in the FB site.

The feed dialog is appearing without error and I can post to wall but when I replace "feed" with "send", it gives an error saying "An error ouccured with MyApp. Pls. try again later.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

The last item in the android post is how to get post dialog method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send in general but there could be some workaround... But that couldn't be generalized in that way... Because you have to use an API for that and there is not currently any support for that what I suppose you can read but can't write... http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/291 is the reference for details...

Comment: Thanks hossaindoula. I am aware of this but this blog post is a 2009 one. Fb recently released the send dialog which allows users to share content with only certain friends of his. I wanted to know how to use this in the android app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: Yeah I told you that there could be some workaround... And this workaround I'll show in my blogspot... Not here... Cause I need to step by step demonstrate everything...

Comment: Do you already have a post about it on your blog? Can you give me the link?

Comment: Currently there is not tutorial on that message sending part in Android Apps to Facebook Message via Facebook custom created Apps... I'll write it upcoming weekend... http://hossaindoula.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a message with the Dialog (source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/):

```
void dialog(Context context, String action, DialogListener listener)
```

action - The type of dialog to call. Currently supported methods are *feed*, *apprequests* and *oauth*.
So, "send" is not a supported method.